# Question about vending machine circuit

Tags: digital-logic, diagram

I have this assignment I finished for a vending machine circuit.  Just as some background, there are three inputs for nickels, dimes and a return option.  The return option is for only one nickel/dime at a time (a crappy system I know).  At 25 cents, you get to choose between pepsi and coke.  At 30 cents a nickel is automatically returned and at 35, a dime. As for outputs, there is RN (return nickel), RD (return dime), DC (drop coke), DP (drop pepsi).

I have my state diagram and table attached here.  Now, there is an extra option to implement a next state decoder (which I will not be doing), but just to satisfy my own curiosity, could someone explain to me briefly how I would go about doing that?

[image: diagram]

[image: table]

Comment: Just noticed my diagram image was cut off a bit.  My states were 0-14 in binary for 0, 0(R), 5, 5(R), 10, 10(R), 15, 15(R), 20, 20(R), 25, 30, 35, DC and DP respectively.

Comment: Nevermind checking it over, I just had that done, but I still would like to know very briefly how to implement an NSD.

Comment: You should account for the possibility that the user doesn't put in any coins in the current clock cycle (i.e N = 0, D = 0 ) and the vending machine stays in it's current state.

Comment: I can't figure out how you assigned bits for your states.For example what bit sequence represents the 5cent stage?

Comment: I had that information added in my first comment.  So 5 cents would be 0010

Comment: So looking at the first line of your table, if the system is in the first stage (0000) and a user inputs a nickel (N = 1, D = 0) then the system goes to the 0R stage(0001)?

Comment: Haha, nope.  Now I know what I could get a few points off for.  The funny thing was I had my TA look at that a few days ago and he didn't pick it up.  Well done.